# passing events from erlang to Clojure

Tags: erlang, clojure, ipc

I'm looking for a way to pass events back and forth between Clojure and erlang.

- has someone done this before?
- how should I encode the (immutable) messages in a flaxable general way?
- Should IPC be used for this? what sort?
- where has this gone wrong for you in the past?

Comment: +1 for a question that makes most people scratch their heads...

Comment: Have not done this before, but I can think of two (potentially bad) options: 1) Use Thrift to make a custom RPC solution. It has support for Java and Erlang. 2) Look at BERT-RPC, created and used by GitHub for Erlang-Ruby RPC, and write a Clojure client library for it.

Comment: alanlcode: dont be shy post this as an answer. these are good ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [jinterface](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/index.html) from clojure and be able to act as an Erlang node and send out multiple Pids associated with your node, in the Erlang cluster.

Comment: +1 using the java library for integration is probably a quick route to this.

Answer (score 2):

You've got lots of options as long as you use a socket (e.g. TCP/IP).

- Have you considered JSON?
- XML?

I can't say I've done Clojure <--> Erlang bridges before but "talking" to Erlang in JSON/XML is sufficiently painless.

Of course you can use the `erl_interface` (binary exchange protocol) but then you'll need (probably unless there is a lib for this) to craft a marshaller for this in Clojure.